# The data context used by LinqDataSource must extend DataContext when the Delete, Insert or Update operations are enabled

Tags: binding, model, formview, linqdatasource

I am looking for a good example of using the Formview for basic CRUD operations in asp.net 4.5 with model binding.  I started out by binding the formview to a linq datasource but when I attempt to update an item I get an error - "The data context used by LinqDataSource 'StreetSegmentsDataSource' must extend DataContext when the Delete, Insert or Update operations are enabled."  I found this from 2011 but is this still the case with 4.5?  [Can I get EnableUpdate and EnableDelete to work on an EF4 LinqDataSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946399/can-i-get-enableupdate-and-enabledelete-to-work-on-an-ef4-linqdatasource)  What is even stanger is that I can get model binding with a GridView bound to a LingDataSource just fine???  So I am thinking it isn't me datasource that is the problem.  I do have the LinqDataSource configured to allow update, insert and delete.

I guess I am not familiar with EntityDataSource - can anyone point me in the right direction?  As I said - Just trying to create a simple page with a formview for CRUD operations using model binding.

Comment: [This might help you mate](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-part-5-binding-ui-using-the-asp-linqdatasource-control)

Comment: [try this as well](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control)